# Dialogflow CX response after conversation is idile

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I would like to know if there is a way using DialogFlow CX to get the chatbot to send a follow up message after a certain x period of time when a customer doesn't respond.

ie: Customer reaches out, chatbot responses, after 2 minutes, the chatbot will send a message like are you still there? message or something like that.

Thanks!

I dont know how to set this up if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

In many ways, it depends on exactly what [integration](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration) you're using and what that integration supports. While there is *some* support for this in Dialogflow CX, it probably isn't as automatic as you want.

If you're building using one of the telephony integrations, there are some [agent settings](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent#settings-speech) that let you set the "No speech timeout" period. At the end of this period (5 seconds by default), if the caller hasn't said anything, then a [no-input event](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#event-built-in) will be triggered and you can use this to repeat the message, prompt if they're still there, or take other actions that may be contextually appropriate.

If you are using a text agent, there isn't any such timeout built in. However, if you can keep track of this on the *client* side (ie - in whatever is sending the messages to Dialogflow), then you can determine if there has been no input for the predetermined amount of time and send an event to Dialogflow that will trigger the reprompt.

For example, if you're using [Dialogflow Messenger](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger), you could setup a [JavaScript event](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#js-events) that sets a timeout when it [gets a response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#df-response-received) from Dialogflow and clears it when the user [sends a request](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#df-request-sent). If it ever times out, it could bring up a message re-prompting the user.